# 400 Bad Request: Node.js Express Ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

I'm new to back end development and ajax. I'm using node.js, express, and ejs. I'm trying to post some data, and return a value using ajax. I keep getting a 404 error and I'm not sure why. Also, I used the express generator to create the project, and also installed body-parser.

Here's the ajax request that's in my index.ejs file. It's within a script tag in the header.

```
function post() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test",
        data: 'TEST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log("Did it work? "+ data);
    });
}
```

Once a button is pressed that ajax executes, and I get a 400 bad request. I think it might be something to do with what's in the index.js file. It might also be the way that the express generator made the server. Again, I'm new to this so any input here would be great.

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.type('json');
    res.send("hi");
  });
module.exports = router;
```

Could it be because the index page is rendered using ejs?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update: 400 fixed, now getting 404**

The 400 error was caused by my trying to send an object rather than a string. Now, I'm getting a 404 error. As requested, my file structure is below.

```
  .
  ├── app.js
  ├── bin
  │   └── www
  ├── package.json
  ├── public
  │   ├── images
  │   ├── javascripts
  │   └── stylesheets
  │       └── style.css
  ├── routes
  │   ├── index.js
  │   └── users.js
  └── views
      ├── error.ejs
      ├── index.ejs
      └── layout.ejs

  7 directories, 9 files
```

I'm still trying to get the grasp of this, and the generator made the files for me. To my understanding, the www file within the bin folder is the startup script. The app.js file is calls everything else. I'm trying to put the post method within the index.js file, but I'm not exactly sure if it should go there or maybe in the app.js file. If you need to know any other info, like what the other files look like I'd be glad to show you.

Comment: As I mention in bellow answer, you must use **valid json string** either you can use string like `'{"text": "from the front end"}'` or `JSON.stringify({"text": "from the front end"})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass a valid json string into data, something like

```
function post() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test",
        data: JSON.stringify({data: 'TEST'}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log("Did it work? "+ data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! That helped, it's not a bad request now. But now I'm getting a 404 when I post? Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Yes, we may help you if you provide little folder & file structure and a small code where you are using current file

Comment: Use `router.post('/test', function(req, res) {` instead of `app` and also you should delete irrelevant code from line number 3rd to 6th

Comment: I hope this help you and also you must not update question with solution

Comment: Sorry about that, I reverted my edits and then added updates as I should have done originally. I tried using router rather than app and I'm still getting that 404. Do you have any other suggestions?